# Passing the selector when using custom jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

Bellow is an example of a jQuery function that calls the callback function after a certain event...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        myCustomFunction : function(callback) {
            var element = $(this[0]);

            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
                callback(e);
            });

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

So far, there are no problems..

But when I use `myCustomFunction`

```
$('#test').myCustomFunction(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

The `$(this)` does not return `$('#test')`. Why? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey it looks like you are over-complicating something here. You can simplify by doing this:

```
$('#test').mouseup(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

If you really want to extend jQuery with a function though, you can do this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    myCustomFunction: function () {
        $(this).mouseup(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    }
});

$('#test').myCustomFunction();
```

Comment: The example above was just a sample of what I was trying to achieve.. Regardless of what the function can does.. is it possible to do what I asked in the question?

Comment: If your question is if it is possible, then look above since I put two solutions. If your question is regarding `this` usage, the answer is because you cannot select `$('#test')` with `$(this)` by nesting your callback within a `$(document)` selector.

Comment: Yeah, my question is about `this`. So, by your last statement, do you mean it isn't possible? How can jQuery achieve this thing in `.each()`  function? It seems like they are able to change the value of `this`!

Comment: `this` is used to reference item within the current scope. If you want to reference `this` for a parent scope, you can use a variable or a proxy. I usually do `var self = this;` when nesting so that I can access the original object via `$(self)`.

Comment: could you please take a look at my answer and tell me whether it is efficient using that method. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found how to achieve that..

Instead of calling the callback function directly like this `callback()`, I tried to call it using the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) `callback.call()` and passed the element using it.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        myCustomFunction : function(callback) {
            var element = $(this[0]);

            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
                callback.call(element[0], e);
            });

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then using `this` in the callback function will reference the selected elements

```
$('#test').myCustomFunction(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```